# How to concat 2nd sheet of every .xlsx files that are in a folder?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have code for appending multiple excel files that are inside a folder. But I want to append the second sheet in all the excel files. By default, pandas take the first sheet while appending. Also, I tried specifying the second sheet name while reading the excel file. But that doesn't work. Pls share ur ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code. Did you try to set an index instead of a name string to specify the sheet of choice?

Comment: import os                                          import pandas as pd pat

Comment: import os                                          import pandas as pd                                                                path = getcwd                                      files = os.listdir(path)                  files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == '.xlsx']                                                        df = pd.DataFrame()                               for f in files_xlsx:                                                    data = pd.read_excel(f, sheetname='sheet2')                               df = df.append(data)

Comment: No, please.... not as comment - in your question. There you can format it nicely as code by indenting with four spaces or simply selecting and pressing `Ctrl`+`k`.

Answer (score 0):

As Pandas 0.24.2 document of [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), specifying the sheet_name and loop files would solve your problem.

```
df = pd.read_excel("folder/filename.xlsx", sheet_name=1)
```